# Executing ArchUnit tests from a java library

Tags: java, testing, archunit

I have a bunch of Java Dropwizard microservices which have a similar structure. My objective is to write a set of ArchUnit test cases which are required to be run in each service and the build should fail if these test cases fail.

Since the checks will be similar, is it possible that I extract out all the test cases in a common library and add it as a dependency in every service ? How to add test cases from a library to be run in the build of a service ?

Answer (score 4):

If you use JUnit, Maven and Maven Surefire Plugin, the task is simple:

- Package all your ArchUnit tests as a Maven artifact, let's say with groupId `org.myproject` and artifactId `myproject-archunit-tests`.
- Add the dependency information to your other artifact's pom with test scope:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.myproject</groupId>
      <artifactId>myproject-archunit-tests</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Configure Maven Surefire Plugin in your other artifact's pom so that tests are included in the test run:

  ```xml
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
      <configuration>
          <dependenciesToScan>
              <dependency>org.myproject:myproject-archunit-tests</dependency>
          </dependenciesToScan>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
  ```

  See also https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan

Answer (score 2):

There is also a [Maven Plugin](https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-maven-plugin) and a [Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/societe-generale/arch-unit-gradle-plugin) that you could add to the build of each microservice.

Other than that, as mentioned it is only about depending on the artifact containing your tests and then executing them somehow. Either by configuring the test executor to pick tests from the test artifact on the classpath, or by following a pattern like described in [the user guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_grouping_rules) where you would have one test inside of the projects that imports all the tests from your library. E.g.

```
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "my.specific.project")
class ArchitectureTest {

    @ArchTest
    static final ArchTests commonRules = ArchTests.in(CommonRules.class);
}
```

The latter would give you the advantage that you can still configure a different import per project.